# Issues with Eclipse using packages

Tags: java, eclipse, git

Guys I am just working on a Compiler for group project and I am experiencing some issues. I am using git for the version control. Quite a lot of times since yesterday, after a merge My eclipse is messing up my packages. I have a src folder and two packages in it and eclipse is showing both packages as src. .
This is causing errors in all of my classes in both of those packages. Does anyone know why is this happening?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you excluding .classpath and .project files from your Git project?

Comment: In my commit, I am adding and pushing everything, but It seems to be the issue with the classpath. Like now i fixed the classpath and forced the push on my repository. It now seems to work okay but I still was wondering what could be possibly causing this issue everytime, Since I always need to fix the classpath when there's a auto-merge.

Comment: Remove the .classpath and .project folders from the remote git repository and then add them to the git ignore list. Make sure all your team membersdo a pull again before committing to upstream.

Answer (score 0):

In general your packages are subdirectories of /src unless you are using the default package (which is not recommended). I would start by checking the actual directory, see what is the actual structure of the files. If there is actually a single folder, then the problem is not git, it's eclipse. Check the project properties -> build path -> source, which is were source folder are configured. Remove useless entries.

It's ok to put the .classpath and .project files in GIT, I usually do, since it's a waste of time to configure everyone's environment when I add libraries, etc. Just be sure to use only relative paths.

I can probably help better if you provide a little more information or a screenshot.